# Cannot import python package I built after installing from github

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

This my first time creating a python package and I am trying to host it on github so I can use it in my code

Its just a simple module with one file, but when I install it with `pip install -r requirements.txt` the metadata folder is showing up in the site-packages but not my actual module file `singleton.py`. Hence I cannot do `import singleton`

My `pyproject.toml`

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=57",
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

My `setup.cfg`

```
[metadata]
name = singleton
version = 1.0.0
url = https://github.com/syntapy/singleton

[options]
package_dir = 
    =src
packages=find:

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

I've tried following the 'using a `src/` layout' in the [Configuring setup() using setup.cfg files documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html), both with `find` and with `singleton` but it doesn't work

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

You should put single Python file in `src/singleton/` along with an `__init__.py`.

The structure is correctly explained in your link:

```
├── src
│   └── mypackage
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── mod1.py
├── setup.py
└── setup.cfg
```

Otherwise, with the old school `setup.py` (with `singleton.py` and `setup.py` in the same folder):

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='singleton',
    version='1.0.0',
    url='https://github.com/syntapy/singleton',
    py_modules = ['singleton'],
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but it still wasn't working. But then I tried to put it in `src/singleton/__init__.py` and that worked. But do you know of a way to make it so I can just have it in a `singleton.py` file?

Comment: I don't know how with `setup.cfg`, but with `setup.py`, it's possible. See edited answer.